# Why UITabBar item do not respond on single tap with iOS 11?

Tags: ios, uistoryboard, uitabbar, ios11, xcode9

I have an app available on app store since iOS 9 and it was working fine but with iOS 11 tab bar items(highlighted in image) are not behaving as per expectation, on tab respective action is not firing it fires when we do swipe action on tabbar.

All the properties are just same as previous(properties shown in image 2)

[image]

[image]

Comment: You are highlighting a UIToolbar, not a UITabBar...

Answer (score 0):

You may have to position your bottom toolbar against the Safe Area if you are planning on supporting iPhoneX, as the bottom part of the screen has a drag bar that replaces the home button and may interfere with the touches on the toolbar.

You can read more about it at [Positioning Content Relative to the Safe Area | Apple Developer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/positioning_content_relative_to_the_safe_area)